# How to pass Textbox id to JavaScript on Button Click OnClientClick in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using Ajax tab Container and two textbox with button when button click i want to send both the textbox id becoz of ajax textbox id changing like(ex. Httabcontainer_txtusername)actual textbox id is txtusername...how to send textbox id to javascript function  when user will click the button...

Comment: Give some standard class to that text and based on the class name ur get id of that textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with Textbox is ID is dynamically changed at runtime, you can fix this problem to Point your given ID to the control by adding property `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the control.
So, at the run time your object ID will remain same as you defined for your control.

Now you can easily use JQuery or JavaScript ID reference like:

```
var txt = $('#id').val();
```

and

```
var newVal = document.getElementById('id').getValue();
var newVal = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find textboxes using jQuery

```
$("[id$=txtusername]")
```

above code will give you all textboxes ending with txtusername id

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your javascript function

```
var TextBox1 = '<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>';
```

You can also use

```
var TextBox1= document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

As this is ajax call you need to use `find`

```
var TextBox1 =$find('<%= txtusername.ClientID %>');
```

Note:This is same as we do to find the ajax ModalpopExtender of asp.net

OR

```
var TextBoxID =$("[id$='txtusername']").attr(id);  //get id of textbox
```

Answer (score 0):

because your id is changing frequently so get it by its name, and you want to gets its id so try this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName( 'yourname' );
```

now you have that element, now gets its id

```
var id = elements[0].getAttribute( 'id' );
```

Answer (score 0):

for solving that Changing ID issue just set  ClientIDMode="static" in asp.net textbox it won't change if you use ajax or not...and we can use orignal textbox id whatever you have given in client side we will assign in javascript